# How do i properly address Clang's UTF-8 string literal warning?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

Similar questions were asked many times, but it seems like i'm still missing something:

```
  auto message = u8"Текст";
  client.sendMessage(channel.ID, message);
```

When compiling this snippet with [-W-c++20-compat flag](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wc-20-compat) with Clang compiler it gives the following warning next to the `u8` literal:

> type of UTF-8 string literal will change from array of const char to array of const char8_t in C++20 [-Wc++20-compat]

The [P1423R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r2.html#remediation) document suggests a number of ways for remediation. I tried the [explicit conversion function approach](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r2.html#conversion_fns) first, but it didn't silence the warning, so decided to implement [emulation with macroses](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r2.html#emulate) then and it didn't make the warning vanish either (apparently because Clang generates this warnings after preprocessor step).

I understand that the given solutions should successfully address the given problem and provide backward/forward compatibility between C++20/pre C++20 standards, so i **could** just ignore this warning. However the answer i'm looking for is how this warning *is supposed* to be addressed? Sometimes it's just impossible to remove u8 literals in your code as it makes drastic difference under some systems, and my case is exactly about this.

Comment: Is the situation that you want to use `u8""` literals to force `UTF-8` but come away with a `char const*` for use throughout the code? Because you could just cast aka `auto m = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(u8"...");`.

Comment: What is `sendMessage`'s signature?

Comment: Maybe simply disable the warning until you upgrade to C++ 20 and fix code as necessary at that point.